# How to stop a timer thread

Tags: python, scapy, traffic, packets

This is my code in which I am using a thread

```
from scapy.all import *
from random import randint
import threading

# Generate packet
pkts = IP(src="10.0.0.1",dst="10.0.0.2")/TCP()/Raw(RandString(size=120))
#print pkts
pkts[TCP].flags = "UFP"

pktList = []
for pktNum in range(0,5):
    pktList.extend(pkts)
    pktList[pktNum][TCP].dport = randint(1,65535) # Pkt has Ran PortNo.
    print pktList[pktNum].summary()
    #print len(pktList[pktNum])
    wrpcap('tcp-packets.pcap',pktList[pktNum])

# Send the list of packets send(pktList)
def send_p():
    start_time=time.time()
    send(pktList)
    totalTime = time.time()-start_time
    print totalTime,"seconds"
    totalBytes=(50*120)/totalTime
    print '%4.1f' % totalBytes, "B/s"
    t=threading.Timer(2,send_p,())
    t.start()

t=threading.Timer(2,send_p,())
t.start()
```

I want to stop thread after some interval of time as in this code doesn't stops until I issue a keyboard interrupt.
How would I do that?

Comment: > threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are indestructible, BuwaHahaha. Use multiprocessing instead, that way you can KILL THEM ALL.

There isn't a `multiprocessing.Timer`, so instead just use `import time` `time.sleep(2)` before running the process.

`t=threading.Timer(2,send_p,())` becomes `t=multiprocessing.Process(target=send_p)`

Full example using your code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

# Code that you want to execute then later execute

time.sleep(2)
t=multiprocessing.Process(target=send_p)
t.start()
time.sleep(100) # "Some interval of time"
if t.is_alive():
    t.terminate() # Kill it with fire! or SIGTERM on linux
```

---

Code block returning information about each run.

```
from scapy.all import *
from random import randint
import threading
import time
import multiprocessing
from itertools import count

# Generate packet
pkts = IP(src="10.0.0.1",dst="10.0.0.2")/TCP()/Raw(RandString(size=120))
#print pkts
pkts[TCP].flags = "UFP"

pktList = []
for pktNum in range(0,5):
    pktList.extend(pkts)
    pktList[pktNum][TCP].dport = randint(1,65535) # Pkt has Ran PortNo.
    print pktList[pktNum].summary()
    #print len(pktList[pktNum])
    wrpcap('tcp-packets.pcap',pktList[pktNum])

# Send the list of packets send(pktList)
def send_p(queue):
    for run_number in count(): # this will run indefinitely, same as while True, must be killed to stop.
        start_time=time.time()
        send(pktList)
        totalTime = time.time()-start_time
        totalBytes=(50*120)/totalTime
        queue.put((run_number, totalTime, totalBytes))

def create_p2p_traffic():
    pass # do stuff


q = multiprocessing.Queue()
t = multiprocessing.Process(target=send_p, args=(q, ))
t.start()

time.sleep(10)

### Runs without P2P traffic

rates = []

while True: # This loop will pull all items out of the queue and display them.
    run = q.get()
    if not run: # When we reach the end of the queue, exit
        break
print "Average rate of {0:.1f} B/s without p2p traffic".format(sum(rates)/float(len(rates)))


### Runs with P2P traffic

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_p2p_traffic)
p.start()

time.sleep(10) # "Some interval of time"

if t.is_alive():
    t.terminate()

if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()

p2prates = []
while True: # This loop will pull all items out of the queue and display them.
    run = q.get()
    if not run: # When we reach the end of the queue, exit
        break
    run_number, total_time, total_bytes = run
    print "Run {run_number} took a total of {total_time}\
at an average rate of {total_bytes:.1f} B/s".format(run_number=run_number,
                                                    total_time=total_time,
                                                    total_bytes=total_bytes)
    p2prates.append(total_bytes)

print "Average rate of {0:.1f} B/s after p2p started".format(sum(p2prates)/float(len(p2prates)))
```

Comment: I want to capture that how many bytes have been captured per second and send different traffic patterns and capture their rates. What I should be doing ?

Comment: I want to start processing after some interval that is I want to capture per second bytes after 1 sec. How would I do that using multiprocessing ?

Comment: Honestly not sure what you're asking in a programmatic sense. If you mean you need to get that information from the processes that are being run, use a [queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: I am simply asking that when I am sending packets I want to calculate the data rate after every one second i.e. transmission of total bytes per second.

Comment: Ah, yeah, with threading it will print to same screen, with multiprocessing you will have to pass that back to the main process to display it. I have updated my answer to include how I would accomplish that.

Comment: What you mean by run_number ?

Comment: It's simply a counter that will increment for each time you run `send(pktList)`, completely unnecessary, just is another metric to know how many times the send operation was performed in that amount of time.

Comment: Basically I donot want to return the byte/sec transmission rate of each packet but the data transmission rate of how many bytes i.e total packets transferred per second

Comment: Yup, that's what that last line will display, you can remove the print before that in the while loop if you want and only display the average bytes per second. It gathers all the rates you generate in `send_p()` into the list `routes` and will average them all out.

Comment: Aaah Ok ! 
well lets say I want to start another process after 10 seconds executing with other processes without effecting anything, than what I should be doing ?
For instance I want to generate peer to peer traffic after 10 seconds of start which transmits data without effecting the already sending http traffic then what should I be doing ?

Comment: Basically load testing at that point I take it? To easy options: 1. Blocking until P2P is done, or 2. time the P2P and kill it after x seconds. Option 1, where it says `time.sleep(100)` simply add the code / function call to the P2P traffic generator. Option 2, create the code as a seperate function, and do another multiporcessing call to it, then add the `time.sleep()` after it.

Comment: I didn't understand what u said, kindly update the code for makint it more easier to understand and I am finding it difficult to generate P2P traffic. How will I do that ?

Comment: I updated the answer to show where I would include the P2P traffic starting. But I honestly have no idea how to generate that, that's a question of it's own. Good luck with your project!

Comment: You didn't updated using the queue so the create_P2P function is not running. The program gets stop after sending the 5 tcp packets and print their average rate. It doesn't sends the P2p traffic.

Comment: CasualDemon, See This Link, this is the code for the above mentioned issues
[Link]    
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6vs99v57hxqmn4c/92F2LvyLMD/finalTraffic.py

Comment: This is what I have done to sent both kind of traffics and its working. Kindly check if it has issues or not.
[link] 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k11iindy0qfjwur/deltatcp1.py